# What is Sitecore xDB best practice for scalability and usage

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, scaling

So my knowledge in this area is limited as most of the implementations I've been involved with have been less focused on the xDB system and as a result I have questions.

Current situation:

- Load Balanced between two CD servers with own SQL Server and MongoDB instance
- One CM with own SQL Server and MongoDB instance

Do both CD servers point to one SQL and MongoDB?

Where does a user access the Analytical data, though CM or through one of the CD servers?

How does this all change if we decide to use Sitecore's Cloud xDB option?

If anyone knows where I can find documentation, has advice to help or provide any pitfalls I might encounter I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure this would make a great question, since there's really not a clear right "answer" and most would be based upon opinion or environment setup.

Comment: We do have a precedence for "Best Practices" questions here however. But the question would need to be re-worded, right now it's 3-4 questions all in one. Asking for a general best-practices recommendation on scalability of Mongo for instance might pass - however I think we have that one on record already.

Comment: I would suggest, you refer to Sitecore documentations like https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/platform/scalability_options and https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/platform/cloud_configuration_options

Comment: I too would suggest breaking this up into multiple different questions. The question, for example, about load-balanced CD servers pointing to a single SQL and MongoDB is a very clear and precise scenario that can be answered. Where to access analytical data is also a clear and precise question, but is only loosely related to the previous one.

Comment: I will resubmit.